# Is my proof that $\gamma$ (the Euler-Mascheroni constant) is transcendental correct?

Tags: proof-verification, transcendental-numbers, transcendence-theory

The Euler-Mascheroni constant $\gamma$ can be defined as $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}(1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+...+\frac{1}{n}-\ln n)$. For every positive integer n (except for 1), the value of this sequence is transcendental. So from the definition, $\gamma$ must be transcendental, too.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Answer (score 11):

No.

$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac\pi n$ is the limit of transcendental numbers and yet rational

Comment: Good, +1. Along those lines, even just $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(\frac1n x + (1-\frac1n)y)$ where $x$ is transcendental and $y$ is not.

Comment: or even just $\frac{y}{n}$

Answer (score 0):

Rationals are dense so find $a_n\rightarrow e$ and $a_n\in\mathbb{Q}$. Then define 
$$b_n=a_n-e.$$